# Update Global context CKAN

Tags: ckan

I need some live data in global CKAN context. 
I render some html from it, with Jinja2. Firstly I used `ckan.lib.app_globals`

```
from ckan.lib.app_globals import app_globals as g

g.my_data = retrive_data_from_other_source
```

The main problem -- `g` updates only once, but i need to keep it synced. To get `g` updated now I need to restart apache, but this isn't an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling I found the best approach. The idea is to use
Template helpers:  http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/theming/templates.html#custom-template-helper-functions

Answer (score 0):

Each CKAN thread has its own copy of g. So if you change it in one thread it will not update others.

It is described as 'global' because it contains info used by all requests, but yes it's essentially read-only once ckan has finished its start-up phase. It's perfect for storing config/settings, but not for what you want.

To share live data between different CKAN requests you're going to need to put it in something external to CKAN, such as redis or memcached, etc.